# How to select from multiple tables with join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all data from databases Startuptier1 and connections where the company id = $select. Both databases have the column 'companyid' with the corresponding row.

None of the information regarding joins that I have found so far online is working. I have also tried unions. I assume I am missing something very obvious?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM startuptier1 
JOIN connections ON startuptier1.companyid = connections.companyid 
WHERE companyid= '$select';";
```

I expect to get the data from both databases from what I've read so far but all I'm getting is an SQL Error.

Comment: database or tables?   update your question and add  the related  tables schema .. and show you exact error message

Comment: What is the SQL error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error probably because, `companyid` is present in both tables and mysql cannot decide on which column to fire `where` condition:

Try the modified query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM startuptier1 
          JOIN connections ON 
               startuptier1.companyid = connections.companyid 
        WHERE startuptier1.companyid in (".$select.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your database account should have appropriate permission. You should be able to perform operations on every database that you are accessing via joins

> **EXAMPLE 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.table1 t1 JOIN DB2.table2 t2 ON t2.column2 = t1.column1;
```

---

> **EXAMPLE 2:**

```
SELECT db1.artist.name, db2.painting.title
  FROM db1.artist INNER JOIN db2.painting
  ON db1.artist.a_id = db2.painting.a_id;
```